# How is the の used in the sentence 願いの叶う家?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の

I'm a little bit familiar with how の is to indicate possession but this just confuses me. Does it translate to "Grant my wish for a family"?

Answer (score 0):

It translates to

"A house that makes wishes come true."

Not sure what the context is of the sentence, with that alone it seems to be the above.

Comment: Yeah, but grammatically speaking, "A house that makes wishes come true" would be 「願いを叶える家」, no?　(「願い**の**叶う家」 = 「願い**が**叶う家」. この「の」の説明を…)

Answer (score 0):

願いの叶う家 = 願いが叶う家 as @choco said. A general rule is that if the construct is `X の Y Z` where X is a pronoun or noun, Y is a verb, and Z is a noun, then の is really が.

For more on why, see the link above.